# Accessing Class property using variable in c#

Tags: c#

I have below model class in c# window application. I have form controls which I want to assign values to model properties after form validation. I have many more controls and many controls are the same. So instead of validating each control separate I want to loop the same controls and validate then in for loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TShopLibrary
{
    public class CustomerModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Contact1 { get; set; }
        public string Contact2 { get; set; }
        public string RefContact { get; set; }
        public decimal ShirtLength { get; set; }
        public List<ShirtBottomTypeModel> ShirtBottomType { get; set; } = new List<ShirtBottomTypeModel>();
        public decimal Sleeve { get; set; }
        public decimal Shoulder { get; set; }
        public decimal Chest { get; set; }
        public decimal ShirtBottom { get; set; }
        public decimal ShalwarLength { get; set; }
        public decimal ShalwarWidth { get; set; }
        public decimal ShalwarBottom { get; set; }
        public decimal ShalwarBottomOpening { get; set; }
        public List<NeckTypeModel> NeckType { get; set; } = new List<NeckTypeModel>();
        public decimal ChestPlateLength { get; set; }
        public decimal ChestPlateWidth { get; set; }
        public decimal NeckWidth { get; set; }
        public decimal NeckHeight { get; set; }
        public decimal Pocket { get; set; }
        public List<SewingTypeModel> SewingType { get; set; } = new List<SewingTypeModel>();
        public decimal Comments { get; set; }
        public decimal CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public decimal UpdtedDate { get; set; }

        public CustomerModel()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

and below is my form code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TShopLibrary;

namespace TShopUI
{
    public partial class AddCustomerForm : Form
    {
        private CustomerModel customermodel = new CustomerModel();
        public AddCustomerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       

        private bool ValidateForm()
        {
           
        }

        private void CustomerSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (ValidateForm())
            {

            }
        }

        private void CustomerNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In my ValidateForm() I want some thing like below.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
if(ctrl.Text!="")
{
 customermodel[ctrl.Name] = ctrl.text;
}
                
            }
```

In the above all is good. The problem is at

customermodel[ctrl.Name] = ctrl.text;

Comment: Hi, "This piece is not working." such a sentence is usually the beginning of a question cascade to find out all the necessary information to get a clear picture of your problem. Please be so kind save us the time and elaborate on this fact. What did actually happen?

Comment: on the first glance: to be able to use the `[..]` on a custom object like in this line: `customermodel[ctrl.Name] = ctrl.text;` you would need to override the indexing operator. Since I don't see that piece of code in your `CustomerModel` class. This should lead to a compilation error. This compilation error can be researched in your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var props = typeof(Control).GetProperties();
foreach (var p in props)
{
    var value = p.GetValue(control_instance);
    if (p.Name == "Text")
        Do stuff....
}
```

Comment: It might be better to first check if it matches and then getting the value of the instance to use it.